# Browser crashes when decoding base64 file

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, blob, pdf.js

When decoding a large (more than 8Mb) base64 file the browser shows a warning script is too busy. But it will only show sometimes and if we click the continue the decoding completes and the file(pdf or epub) is shown.How to avoid this script busy message.(making the file base64 is necessary so cant change that)

Comment: Don't use base64 -- decoding from base64 increase needed memory up to 6 times (PDF.js cannot accept base64, so you probably already decoding it yourself, also 48MB is not an issue for the modern hardware) You probable set disableWorker=true (or using pdf.combined.js), which triggers slow script message -- don't do that, use standard settings.

Comment: I am using pdf.js along with pdf.worker.js and viewer.js . when console log PDFJS object it shows disableWorker=false .

Comment: Would you like to prepare an example to reproduce the issue? http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: does converting a large base64 string to blob using atob can cause browser crash?

Comment: well the problem is solved. Reducing slice size when converting to blob solved the problem.Thank you

Answer (score -1):

I believe you can use Web Workers to stop unresponsive script prompt occurring.

See [Mozilla Web Workers API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers)

I also came across this SO answer which seems appropriate:

[JS: Prevent Unresponsive Script Warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29134753/js-prevent-unresponsive-script-warnings)

Comment: PDF.js is using web workers, problem that ignorant people disableWorker or use pdf.combined.js instead of standard settings/library.